# How can I seperate all the titles from json file whose title contain a given word?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

Here's a piece of function just return props to element named box in React.
In this `MovieDatabase` is a JSON file which contains titles of different movies. I want to only that movies whose name includes "Star Wars".

```
const showMovies = MovieDatabase.map((movie) =>{
const aa = movie.title.contains("Star Wars")
return (
    <Box movieName = {aa} />
);})
```

Comment: parse the JSON then iterate over the object, pushing `this` into a starWars array if `this.title` string match finds "Star Wars". hint: .lowerCase()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it'd be better to filter separate from the component.

Here's a way:

```
// assuming the DB is something like this based on your .map example
const MovieDatabase = [
    { title: 'Star Wars: II', id: 0 },
    { title: 'Star Wars: I', id: 1 },
    { title: 'Star Wars: IV', id: 2 },
    { title: 'Moon', id: 3 }
  ]

// array of star wars movies
const starWars = MovieDatabase.filter(movie => movie.title.includes('Star Wars'))

// component to render movies ( doesn't care about anything but rendering )
const MovieBoxes = movies => movies.map(movie => (
  <Box key={movie.id} movieName={movie.title} />
)
```

You could further improve it by wrapping the filter in a function that takes a keyword and passes it to includes so you can find any movie.

Comment: 'MovieDatabase.filter()' 
returns boolen value not the array.
Edit : Also its showing error that ' movie.title.includes() ' is not a function.

Comment: What is MovieDatabase then? @ManishPant In the top post, you used a `.map` on it indicating that it's an array.

Comment: MovieDatabase is json file.

Comment: Leave it. got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const array = [{
  title: 'Star Wars',
  duration: 107
}, {
  title: 'Star Wars',
  duration: 103
}, {
  title: 'Lord Of The Rings',
  duration: 500
}]

const filterArray = array.filter(film => film.title === 'Star Wars')

console.log(filterArray)
```

Comment: This works but if movie name is like “Star Wars: The last Jedi”, it doesn’t shows up

Answer (score 0):

You can also return `null` in your `map()` as your filter without needing to explicitely use `Array#filter()` since React will not render that

```
const showMovies = MovieDatabase.map((movie) =>{
    const {title} = movie
    return title.contains("Star Wars") ? <Box movieName = {title} /> : null;
})
```